# Divergence of the sum and subtraction of logarithms

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, logarithms

I've been stuck with a problem involving factorials, which maybe is worth it working with logarithms.

What I have is this:
$$ f(n) = \frac{(k(n)!)^2}{(n-1)!}$$

Where $k(n)$ is a strictly increasing function of $n$ (because of the factorials, there's no problem in picking the ceiling or the floor, I think).

The question is: what is the growth rate of $k(n)$ that makes $f(n)$ go to zero as $n$ grows?

I've tried working with logarithms, reaching:
$$\tilde{f}(n) = \sum_{i=1}^{k(n)} \log(i) - \sum_{j=k(n)+1}^{n-1} \log(j)$$

(and then I wish $k(n)$ to be such that $\tilde{f}$ goes to $-\infty$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$)

I've tried playing with it a little bit and my "guess" is that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{k(n)}{\sqrt[3]{n}}=0$. I'm not sure if this is correct or not but at least on the computer that seems to work (super slow convergence when $\delta$ is small).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: $k(n) = (n-1)/2$ would work

Comment: Thanks! What if instead I had (for some integer $j \in \{2,...,k(n)\}$),
$$ f(n) = \frac{(k(n)!)^2}{(n-1)!} \frac{(n-j)!}{((k(n)-j)!)^2}$$

Would that still work?

Comment: I don't think so, basically the bottom is product of $n-i$ from $i=1$ to $j-1$ while the top is product of $(k(n) - i) ^2$ from $i=0$ to $j-1$, you'd basically need $k(n) $ to act more like square root probably slightly lower like $k(n) =n^{\frac12 - \epsilon}$

Comment: Thank you so much!